# Does the adjective 'ridiculous' always mean something bad?

Tags: adjectives

I have heard this word a lot in British English and I'm wondering if it can be used to describe good situations.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If someone gave me a ridiculous wad of money I wouldn't object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Ridiculous" is a common adjective of praise among U.S. skateboarders and snowboarders when someone performs a difficult (seemingly impossible) trick well.

From the Urban Dictionary:

ridiculous
Where something is hot, cool, or off the hook

Comment: Did Zoolander have anything to do with this, you reckon?

Answer (score 2):

I like Zan700’s answer.  It is the *exception that proves the rule*.

All the way back to Latin *ridiculus* has been a pejorative adjective.  the ending ‘*iculus’* is a diminutive (and so condescending) addition to the stem of ‘*rideo*’ <= I laugh>.

The poet Horace, in his *Ars Poetics* wittily mocks pretentiously grandiose openings to pompous and turgid and overlong epic poems

> Parturient montes; nascetur ridiculus mus
>   The mountains will go into labour; out will come a silly little mouse

Zan700’s example shows a popular ‘slang’ use of adjectives/adverbs to mean virtually the opposite of their normal meaning.  ‘Wicked’ is a well known instance of this; ‘literally’ is another.  Zan’s expression of how *ridiculous* is “off the clock”. they are ‘so good or cool..., it’s *ridiculus*’ or, we hear *‘it isn’t true’*.

But the core meaning remains (for now) ‘laughable’, ‘not worth taking seriously’.

Comment: @KJO Yes, yes indeed. Aristotle himself (not famed for his sense of humour) placed comedy in the category of the ‘laughable’ (το γελοιον - geloion).